# Set rules for a request parameter based on the values of other multiple parameters in Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am using Joi to validate the requests for my API.

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. If the platform is `aws` and the engine is `premium`, then the field pitch should not be present.
2. In other cases the field pitch is optional and the valid values are on of `default`, `x-low`, `low`, `medium`, `high` and `x-high`.

I have tried something like this but it is not working for me.

```
 const schema = Joi.object({
        platform: Joi.string().valid("aws","google","azure").required(),
        engine: Joi.string().valid("standard","premium").required(),
        pitch: Joi.when(Joi.object({platform: Joi.valid('aws'), engine: Joi.valid('premium')}),{
            then: Joi.forbidden(),
            otherwise: Joi.string().valid('default', 'x-low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'x-high'),
        })
 });
```

Any clue how to achieve this using Joi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **when** should be relative to your object:

```
Joi.object({
    platform: Joi.string().valid("aws","google","azure").required(),          
    engine: Joi.string().valid("standard","premium").required(),                     
    pitch: Joi.string().valid('default', 'x-low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'x-high'),
})
    .when(Joi.object({ platform: Joi.valid('aws'), engine: Joi.valid('premium') }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({ pitch: Joi.forbidden() })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This schema will make the **pitch** forbidden when **platform** is `aws`, and **engine** is `premium`

```js
const pitch = Joi.when(
  'platform', {
    is: 'aws',
    then: Joi.when(
      'engine', {
        is: 'premium',
        then: Joi.forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.string().valid('default', 'x-low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'x-high')
      }
    )
  }
)

const schema = Joi.object({
  platform: Joi.string().valid("aws", "google", "azure").required(),
  engine: Joi.string().valid("standard", "premium").required(),
  pitch
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Is there any shorthand for this?

Comment: You can store `pitch` in its own variable and then reference it in your schema object.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code, please?